# How to get BehaviorSubject-like behavior from a filtered Observable?

Tags: rx-java

I have an Observable to which I've applied a filter.  I'd like to get BehaviorSubject-like semantics from it, such that upon subscription, the subscriber receives the last item that passed the filter.  However, BehaviorSubject doesn't seem be be designed to be stuck in the middle of a chain, but rather only as a source.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `compose` to chain them, such as:

```
public class BehaviorSubjectTransformer<T> implements Observable.Transformer<T, T> {

    @Override
    public Observable<T> call(Observable<T> o) {
        BehaviorSubject<T> subject = BehaviorSubject.create();
        o.subscribe(subject);
        return subject;
    }

    public static <T> Observable.Transformer<T, T> create() {
        return new BehaviorSubjectTransformer<T>();
    }
}

@Test
public void foo() {
    Observable<Integer> o = Observable.just(1, 2, 3).concatWith(Observable.never()).compose(BehaviorSubjectTransformer.create());
    o.subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Integer v) {
            System.out.println("1: " + v);
        }
    });
    o.subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Integer v) {
            System.out.println("2: " + v);
        }
    });
}
```